# Removing Files with specific ending. Need something more specific

Tags: wordpress, bash, file, terminal, thumbnails

I'm trying to purge all thumbnails created by Wordpress because of a CMS switchover that I'm planning.

```
find  -name \*-*x*.* | xargs rm -f
```

But I dont know bash or regex well enough to figure out how to add a bit more specifity such as only the following will be removed

All generated files have the syntax of

```
<img-name>-<width:integer>x<height:integer>.<file-ext> syntax
```

Comment: did you want to remove the files which contain `<img-name>-<width:integer>x<height:integer>.<file-ext> syntax` line? Did the filenames contain `.` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't quote or escape all your wildcards, so the shell will try to expand them before `find` executes.

Quoting it should work

```
find -name '*-*x*.*'| xargs echo rm -f
```

Remove the `echo` when you're satisfied it works. You could also check that two of the fields are numbers by switching to `-regex`, but not sure if you need/want that here.

**regex soultion**

```
find -regex '^.*/[A-Za-z]+-[0-9]+x[0-9]+\.[A-Za-z]+$' | xargs echo rm -f
```

*Note: I'm assuming `img-name` and `file-ext` can only contain letters*

Comment: Yeah thats what I'd like, but I have little experience with regex

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
find -type f |  grep -P '\w+-\d+x\d+\.\w+$' | xargs rm
```

If you have spaces in the path:

```
find -type f  |  grep -P '\w+-\d+x\d+\.\w+$' | sed -re 's/(\s)/\\\1/g' | xargs rm
```

Example:

```
find -type f |  grep -P '\w+-\d+x\d+\.\w+$' | sed -re 's/(\s)/\\\1/g' | xargs ls -l
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tiago tiago 0 Jun 22 15:14 ./image-800x600.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tiago tiago 0 Jun 22 15:17 ./test 2/test 3/image-800x600.png
```

Answer (score 0):

The below GNU `find` command will remove all the files which contain this `<img-name>-<width:integer>x<height:integer>.<file-ext> syntax` string. And also i assumed that the corresponding files has `.` in their file-names.

```
find . -name "*.*" -type f -exec grep -l '<img-name>-<width:integer>x<height:integer>.<file-ext> syntax' {} \; | xargs rm -f
```

**Explanation:**

- `.` Directory in which find operation is going to takeplace.(`.` represnts your current directory)
- `-name "*.*"` File must have dot in their file-names.
- `-type f` Only files.
- `-exec grep -l '<img-name>-<width:integer>x<height:integer>.<file-ext> syntax' {}` print the file names which contain the above mentioned pattern.
- `xargs rm -f` For each founded files, the filename was fed into xargs and it got removed.